# Solving a system of Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recursion, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose I have this binary recurrent sequence $\{B_{n}\}$ called balancing sequence, satisfying $B_{n} = 6B_{n-1}-B_{n-2}$ with initial terms $(B_{0},B_{1}) = (0,1).$ This sequence has following properties :

$1. 2|B_{n} \iff 2|n,$

$2.B_{2n+1}-B_{2n-1} \equiv 2 ~(mod~4)$ and $B_{2n+1}B_{2n-1} \equiv 3 ~(mod~4)$

Similar results can be found with any other modulus.

Suppose we have the following system of Diophantine equations

$B_{2n-1}X+1 = B_{2n+1}(B_{2n+1}-B_{2n-1})A^2,$

$4B_{2n}X+1 = B_{2n+1}(B_{2n+1}-4B_{2n})C^2,$

$B_{2n+1}X+1 = (B_{2n+1}-4B_{2n})(B_{2n+1}-B_{2n-1})D^2,$

where $X,n,A,C,D$ are integer variables.

My aim is to show that above system does not yield any solution.
I have shown that when $n \equiv 1 ~(mod~3)$, for (eq-3) $LHS \equiv 1 ~(mod~7)$ but $RHS \equiv 0,3,5,6 ~(mod~7).$ I am failing to show for the case when $n \equiv 0,2 ~(mod~3).$ In which way can I show so?

Comment: what is it that you actually want to know  about the sequence $B_n \; ? \; \; $ What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: possibly your supervisor, lots of articles with balancing sequences by https://www.suniv.ac.in/faculty_images/profile_1533000153.pdf  Prasanta Kumar Ray

Comment: I want to get it shown that above system does not have any solution, I have achieved it for the case when $n \equiv 1 ~(mod~3).$

Comment: System can reduce as

$(B_{2 n+1}(A^2+C^2-D^2)+2X)^2-(A-C-D)(A+C-D)(A-C+D)(A+C+D)B_{2 n+1}^2=4D^2$